# When to use which method to create object when dealing with one - many relation in c#

Tags: c#, oop, one-to-many, dto

I'm currently having a few object that save customers and other details.
I have

- Customer(Parent object)
- Company (Child of Customer)
- Bank Branch (Child of Customer)
- Bank

My Database will have

**Bank Table**

- Bank Id (primary key)
- Bank Name

**BankBranch Table**

- Branch Id (primary key)
- Bank Id (foreign key)
- Branch Details

I have the Bank Branch and Bank (Which have a list of Bank Branch under the bank)
now when I'm creating the model, I'm confuse with the bank and bank branch.

**Most of my situation**, I'll use bank branch as a customer to record the files.
**But **the system will also have a page to deal with bank, user will get to view list of Bank and list of bank branch will get be displayed when each bank is selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBVd0.png)

Should I do :

1. bank with only id and name & branch with a bank as a property

```
    public class Bank {
        int bankId {get;set}
        string bankNme {get;set;}
    }
    public class BankBranch : Customer {
        Bank bank {get;set;}
        string branchDetails {get;set;}
    }
```

2. Bank with list of branch & branch with only branch details

```
    class Bank{
        int bankId {get;set}
        string bankNme {get;set;}
        List<BankBranch> branchList {get;set;}
    }
    public class BankBranch : Customer {
        string branchDetails {get;set;}
    }
```

3. Bank with list of branch & branch with a bank as a property

```
    public class Bank{
        int bankId {get;set}
        string bankNme {get;set;}
        List<BankBranch> branchList {get;set;}
    }
    public class BankBranch : Customer {
        Bank bank {get;set;}
        string branchDetails {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing your intention, I don't think `BankBranch` should be inheriting from (is a) `Customer`, instead `Customer` should have a reference property to (has a) `BankBranch`.

Comment: Basically I have 2 types of customer which is (company and bank branch). My problem here is, I'm confuse how should I define the relation between bank and bank branch